# HTML5 Audio - Not working IOS browsers

Tags: javascript, ios, html, audio, mobile

I have a list of music tracks, which are stored in AWS S3. 
Using Javascript and HTML5 I am able to play the audio tracks in browsers on Desktop and Android.

The button to click 'play' is not clickable on iOs.

I know the user needs to initiate 'play'. So I added a 'load' event on the click of the logo, but it is still not giving me anything..

How can I best write an initialise method so audios can play on iOs???

**HTML**

```
<div id="logo" onclick="loadTracks();">
</div>

<ul id="list">
                <% @track_keys.each.with_index do |track, index| %>
                        <li class="track-list">
                            <audio preload="auto" type="audio/mp4" class="<%= track %>" onended="startNext(<%= index %>);" id="audiosrc">
                                <source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/yo-man/<%= track %>" type="audio/mpeg">
                            </audio>
                            <div class="playButton name" onclick="playTune(<%= index %>);" id="<%= track %>"><%= track %></div>
                            <div class="pauseButton name" onclick="hitPause(<%= index %>);" id="Paused<%= track %>"><%= track %></div>
                        </li>
                    <% end %>
                </ul>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("audio").on("play", function() {
      var _this = $(this);
      var pauseButton = $('.pauseButton');
      $("audio").each(function(i,el) {
        if(!$(el).is(_this))
        $(el).get(0).pause();
      });
    });

});

var tracks = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
var trackArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(tracks);

var startNext = function(position) {
    //check in here if this is last track
    //if it is, loop back to start
    trackArray[position + 1].play();
};

var spinner = function() {
    $('.sk-spinner-wandering-cubes').show();
    $('.artist').css("opacity", ".5");
};

function isPlaying() {
    for (i = 0; i < trackArray.length; i++) {
        if (trackArray[i].paused) {
            stylePaused(trackArray[i]);
        };
    };
};

function loadTracks() {
    for (i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {
        tracks[0].load();
        tracks[0].onloadeddata = function() {
            alert("loaded track");
        };
    };
};

function whenPlaying(position) {
    var track = trackArray[position];
    var play = track.className;
    var pause = 'Paused' + play;
    var element = document.getElementById(play);
    var otherElement = document.getElementById(pause);
    track.onplaying = function() {
        element.style.display = 'none';
        otherElement.style.display = 'inline-block';
        isPlaying();
    };
};

function playTune(position) { 
    var track = trackArray[position];
    track.play();
    whenPlaying(position);
};

function hitPause(position) {
    var track = trackArray[position];
    track.pause();
    stylePaused(track);
};

function stylePaused(track) {
    var play = track.className;
    var pause = 'Paused' + play;
    var element = document.getElementById(play);
    var otherElement = document.getElementById(pause);
    if (track.paused) {
        otherElement.style.display = 'none';
        element.style.display = 'inline-block';
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying the button works locally? If so I had this problem myself. Have you changed the name of any .mp3 file name anywhere in your code at any point while you've been uploading it to iOS? If you have at any point uploaded two different file names it seems to get confused. Change everything to completely different file names and upload it again. Worked for me.